# Carousel gallery with filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**I will try to explain to you, with my limited english, what I'm trying to do**

1. I have an image gallery on my page and I've created this gallery
   with [cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) and
   [lightGallery](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/)
2. I have a filter link on my carousel (animal,sports,natural,all)

**So what I want to do ?**

For example: if I click animal, then only show me `[data-id="animal"]` div and hide another div different from `[data-id="animal"]`

**What I have done so far ?**

I've created my gallery correctly. It works very well so far and as I expect.cycle2 is working and when you click any image then it is opening on popup(lightgallery)

**What I haven't done so far ?**

Everything is okay until you click any category. When you choose any category, neither cycle2 or lightgallery are working..

Then, after this filtering, lightgallery must work or be generated again (I guess).

**More simply what do I want?**

Filterable photo/image gallery only this what I want to thing

**Any Example that you can show us ?**

For example [this](http://www.bootstrapzen.com/preview/351/) - only as a logic - but this is the only example and I want to do only using cycle2 and jquery I need improve myself and see something on jquery.

If you check my category id, name, and `.item` data-id name, I'm sure you will understand what I'm trying to do.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function generateSlider() {
    $('#myCarousel').cycle({
      next: "#single-right",
      log: false,
      fx: 'fade',
      caption: '.cycle-caption',
      captionTemplate: "{{title}}",
      pauseOnHover: true,
      pager: "#single-pager",
      pagerTemplate: "<img class='lazyload' data-src='{{exthumbimage}}'' width='60' height='60'>",
      prev: "#single-left",
      slides: "div[data-hidden='false']"
    });
  }
  generateSlider();

  $('#myCarousel').lightGallery({
    selector: "div[data-hidden='false']",
    exThumbImage: "data-exthumbimage",
    loadYoutubeThumbnail: true,
    youtubeThumbSize: 'default',
    loadVimeoThumbnail: true,
    vimeoThumbSize: 'thumbnail_medium',
  });



  $("#filter li").on("click", function() {
    var activeId = $(this).attr("id");
    if (activeId == "show-all") {
      $("div").attr("data-hidden", "false");
    } else {
      $("div").attr("data-hidden", "true");
      $("div[data-id = '" + activeId + "']").attr("data-hidden", "false");
    }
    $("#myCarousel").cycle("destroy");
    generateSlider();
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
.mySlideShow {
  width: 700px;
  position: relative;
}

.item img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#single-pager img {
  margin: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

#filter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10%;
  z-index: 100;
}

#filter li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px;
}

.cycle-caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 14%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lightgallery/latest/css/lightgallery.css'>

<div class="mySlideShow">
  <div id="myCarousel">
    <div class="item" data-src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/49a/massive-gear-1255802.jpg" data-exthumbimage="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/fa7/my-ride-1552678.jpg" data-id="animals" data-hidden="false" data-title="image 1">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/f7a/gear-1462890.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/7ae/autos-1194364.jpg" data-exthumbimage="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/5f6/kaputtes-auto-1564173.jpg" data-id="sports" data-hidden="false" data-title="image 2">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/20e/some-grill-1450817.jpg" />
    </div>


    <div class="item" data-src="https://vimeo.com/1084537" data-exthumbimage="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/thumb-v-y-2.jpg" data-id="natural" data-hidden="false" data-title="this is the video">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/c23/cat-1396828.jpg" />
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="single-pager">
  </div>
  <ul id="filter">
    <li id="animals">Animals</li>
    <li id="sports">Sports</li>
    <li id="natural">Natural</li>
    <li id="show-all">All</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="cycle-caption"></div>
</div>


<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lightgallery@1.3.5,lg-fullscreen@1.0.1,lg-hash@1.0.1,lg-pager@1.0.1,lg-share@1.0.1,lg-thumbnail@1.0.1,lg-video@1.0.1,lg-autoplay@1.0.1'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/3.0.0/lazysizes.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js'></script>
```

Also, you can see my demo on [codepen too](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/WjOEeE)

Comment: Just a quick note: you can use jQuery method `.data("hidden", "false")` instead of `.attr("data-hidden", "false")`. It's neater, and I suppose there are other benefits

Comment: yes I know but this was not my answer than I look for :)

Comment: I know, I was just giving some positive input...

Comment: then thank you @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify in the CSS to make the `data-hidden=true` actually hidden.

```
div[data-hidden=true] {
    display: none;
}
```